# React - Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Greetings I'm trying to debug some code right now, not sure how to fix this useEffect that I have in my header to detect for screen size view. Here is the error I'm getting for the useEffect:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.

My code:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    mobileView: false,
    drawerOpen: false,
});

const { mobileView, drawerOpen } = state;

useEffect(() =>
{
    const setResponsiveness = () =>
    {
        return window.innerWidth < 1000
            ? setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, mobileView: true }))
            : setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, mobileView: false }));
    };

    setResponsiveness();

    window.addEventListener("resize", () => setResponsiveness());
}, []);
```

The dependency array is already empty, im not sure what else to put in there though?

Comment: This happens when you try to update the state but component has already unmounted,  because state update is async.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not useEffect that is causing the problem, it's window resize event which is being excuted whenever window size changes.

You are adding `resize` event to window when your function mounts. but when you unmount the component, `resize` event is still listening and whenever window size changes your `setResponsiveness` function will be called. and `setResponsiveness` will try to update the state values of unmounted component. So basically your functional component is leaking memory because even though it has unmounted `setResponsiveness` is still attached to as a callback to windo `resize` event.

You should always remove component specific event listener either in `componentWillUnmount` or in `useEffect` return function, depending on component type.

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    mobileView: false,
    drawerOpen: false,
});

const { mobileView, drawerOpen } = state;

function setResponsiveness() {
    return window.innerWidth < 1000
        ? setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, mobileView: true }))
        : setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, mobileView: false }));
}

useEffect(() => {
    setResponsiveness();
    window.addEventListener("resize", setResponsiveness);
    // return a cleanup function which will remove the event listener
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("resize", setResponsiveness);
    };
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the listener by returning a callback from `useEffect`, which'll run when the component unmounts.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const setResponsiveness = () => {
        return window.innerWidth < 1000
            ? setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, mobileView: true }))
            : setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, mobileView: false }));
    };

    setResponsiveness();

    window.addEventListener("resize", setResponsiveness);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", setResponsiveness);
}, []);
```